# Como gerar números aleatórios em javascript, de forma diferenciada

Tags: javascript

Preciso gerar aleatórios em **javascript**, de forma que eles só sejam gerado de 5 em 5 e de que esteja dentro de uma limitação, por exemplo 5 a 555.
Exemplo: 5, 355, 425, 125, 550

- Números múltiplos de 5 (5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40...)
- Os números devem ter no mínimo 5 e no máximo 555!

Comment: Gerados de 5 em 5 significa sempre gerar 5 números? O fato dos 5 números que deu como exemplo serem múltiplos de 5 foi mera coincidência? O que já tentou fazer? Qual foi a dificuldade encontrada?

Comment: Editei a pergunta! Não tentei nada, sou novato em javascript ;-; estou precisando para um game html5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De forma simples:

```
Math.round(Math.random() * 550 / 5) * 5 + 5;
```

Se quiser algo com valores variáveis ou que possa ser facilmente chamado, pode criar uma função:

```
function myRandom(min, max, multiple) {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) / multiple) * multiple + min;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Basta gerar um número de 1 até 111 e então multiplicar por 5, assim terá um resultado entre 1*5 até 111*5. Acredito que essa é a solução mais fácil e clara de entender, talvez até mais rápida.

---

Uma maneira fácil, e relativamente segura, de fazer isso seria pegar os 7 bits menos significativos de um byte e descarta-los se for maior que 111 ou menor que 1.

```js
function NumeroAleatorio() {
  while (true) {
    // Obtemos o numero aleátorio entre 0 até 255
    var numero = new Uint8Array(1);
    window.crypto.getRandomValues(numero);

    // Obtemos apenas os 7 primeiros bits, fazendo ser de 0 até 127.
    numero = numero[0] & 0x7F;

    // Se for válido, retornamos ele multiplicado por 5.
    if (numero >= 1 && numero <= 111) {
      return numero * 5;
    }
  }
}

document.write("Gerado: " + NumeroAleatorio())
```

---

Isso utiliza o `window.crypto.getRandomValues` que é mais seguro, porém mais lento que o `Math.Random`. Nos comentário mencionou que seria para um jogo, dependendo do caso o `Math.Random` seja melhor, por ser mais rápido.

Existe uma possibilidade de 14%, se minhas contas estiverem certas, do valor estar fora do desejado (do 1 até 111), se o usuário for muito azarado a página poderá ficar num loop infinito, se todas as tentativas estiverem dentro dos 14%.

Answer (score 0):

Tente algo como isto:

```js
function obterNumeroAleatorio(n1, n2) {
  const min = Math.ceil(n1);
  const max = Math.floor(n2);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

function modificarNumeroParaSerMultiploDeCinco(n) {
  const numeroDivisivelPorCinco = Math.round(n / 5) * 5;
  return numeroDivisivelPorCinco;
}

const numeroAleatorio = obterNumeroAleatorio(5, 555);
const numeroFinal = modificarNumeroParaSerMultiploDeCinco(numeroAleatorio);

console.log('numeroAleatorio:', numeroAleatorio);
console.log('numeroFinal:', numeroFinal);
```

Na primeira constante, o número é gerado de forma aleatória, e na segunda é feito com que ele seja múltiplo de 5. O que você precisa provavelmente é apenas do `numeroFinal`.