# Como posso converter esse código PHP para JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript

Fiz esse código em PHP e preciso usar ele em JavaScript porém não sei nem como começar a converter ele:

```php
$codigo_verificador = strtr(rtrim(base64_encode(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32))), '='), '+/', '-_');

$codigo_desafio = strtr(rtrim(base64_encode(hash('sha256', $codigo_verificador, true)), '='), '+/', '-_');

echo "Código verificador: {$codigo_verificador}";  
echo "Código desafio: {$codigo_desafio}";
```

Comment: precisa estudar ambas as linguagues para entender as diferenças. de qualquer forma, muita coisa do php não tem pronto no javascript, vai precisar procurar várias soluções pra ir convertendo esse código

Comment: já deu uma pesquisada no site? deve ter respostas pra tudo isso, olha só: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/295491/57220

Comment: geram um token deve ser feito do "lado server", então precisa fazer isso no php, senão seu código não será seguro, pode ser facilmente manipulado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui fazer, esses dois códigos deram certo para mim

**TESTE4**

```
const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4');

let code = uuidv4()
console.log("Code: " + code);

let hexadecimal = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(code)
console.log("Hexadecimal: " + hexadecimal);

let base64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hexadecimal).replace(/[\/]/g, '_').replace(/[+]g, '-').replace(/[=]/g, '')
console.log("HexToBase64: " + base64);

let sha256 = CryptoJS.SHA256(base64)
console.log("Base64ToSHA256: " + sha256);

let sha256_base64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(sha256).replace(/[\/]/g, '_').replace(/[+]/g, '-').replace(/[=]/g, '')
console.log("Sha256toBase64: " + sha256_base64);
```

**TESTE5**

```
const randomize = require('randomatic');

let code1 = randomize(32)
console.log('Code: ' + code1);

let hexadecimal1 = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(code1)
console.log('CodeToHex: ' + hexadecimal1);

let base641 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hexadecimal1).replace(/[\/]/g, '_').replace(/[+]/g, '-').replace(/[=]/g, '')
console.log('HexToBase64: ' + base641);

let sha2561 = CryptoJS.SHA256(base641)
console.log('Base64ToSHA256: ' + sha2561);

let sha256_base641 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(sha2561).replace(/[\/]/g, '_').replace(/[+]/g, '-').replace(/[=]/g, '')
console.log('Sha256ToBase64: ' + sha256_base641);
```

Answer (score 0):

Você quer utilizar os valores de $codigo_verificador e $codigo_desafio num código javascript? Basta jogar os valores em um input hidden e capturá-los normalmente.

No html:

```
<input type='hidden' id='codigo_verificador' value='<?=$codigo_verificador;?>'/>
<input type='hidden' id='codigo_desafio' value='<?=$codigo_desafio;?>'/>
```

No javascript:

```
var codigo_verificador = document.querySelector('#codigo_verificador');
var codigo_desafio = document.querySelector('#codigo_desafio');
```